# "The remote server returned an error: (403) WMT-Blockwithlink" error in C# when connecting to powerbi server

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, powerbi

When calling a C# web api from postman and localhost url, I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (403) WMT-Blockwithlinks." error. While the same parameter request works just fine in stage and production i.e., when I modify the url of localhost to QA and Prod.

**localhost url**: https://localhost:5001/api/CFRXXX/Tables //gives the above mentioned error

**Stage url**: https://ir-analysis-service.XYZ.com/api/CFRXXX/Tables //works fine

Yesterday it worked all fine by localhost url as well. I am trying to connect to Microsoft powerbi server. I tried googling the error but didn't get much support.

Comment: That doesn't look like a Power BI Report Server API. https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/PBIRS/2.0

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Inside our endpoint i.e., "/api/{database}/Tables" we create a connection string to connect to powerbi server, something like: "Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/org/DP&A Prod;User Id=;Password=;Catalog=\"CFRXXX Dashboard\";;"

Comment: Using ADOMD.NET to connect to the XML/A endpoint of your Power BI Premium Workspace?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, yes that's right. I am using ADOMD.NET to connect to XML/A endpoint in Power BI premium workspace

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from powerbi side, automatically resolved